# Stopping classbreakvalues from changing symbology of point layer (remove strokes) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, symbology, outline

I'm using ArcMap 10.4.1.

I am trying to update a point layer symbology with a premade lyr file, then adjusting it's class break values in arcpy. It's working fine, only it changes the symbols back to default (while the colours stay correct). I don't want my points to have a stoke/outline and can't change that with arcpy, so thats a problem.

Here's my code:

```
updateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "FC", df)[0]
FClyrpath = "FCsymology.lyr"
sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(FClyrpath)
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df,updateLayer,sourceLayer, symbology_only = True)

lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "FC", df)[0]

if lyr.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_COLORS":
    lyr.symbology.valueField = "depth"
    lyr.symbology.classBreakValues = [3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 72]

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

This is what my premade ".lyr" symbology looks like:

[image: lyr]

This is what happens when changing the classbreakValues: The classification is good, the strokes around the symbol not.

[image: after]

I also tried changing the default symbology in AdvancedArcMapSettings, but no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with some polygon layers and found that it is an ESRI-related bug. See [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214865/applysymbologyfromlayer-management-sets-polygon-outlines-to-default#216984) for more details on it.

Comment: In a case like this it is probably best to raise a flag and suggest that this is a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had been stuggeling with this for a long time!